# Remove 2 duplicated swap sublists in list

Tags: python, list, swap

I have a two-dimensional list like this:

```
[[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 7], [5, 2], [6, 1], [7, 3], [8, 9], [9, 8]]
```

I want to remove all the sublists that are duplicates but in reverse order (ie: `[1, 6]` and `[6, 1]`, `[3, 7]` and `[7, 3]`).

The result should be:

```
[[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: Do you want to preserve the order?

Comment: no, the order is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by checking if the sorted list is already had already been added. Like this:

```
data = [[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 7], [5, 2], [6, 1], [7, 3], [8, 9], [9, 8]]
new_data = []
for lst in data:
    if sorted(lst) not in new_data:
        new_data.append(lst)
print(new_data)  # => [[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 7], [8, 9]]
```

This works because `[1, 6]` and `[6, 1]` return the same sorted list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set` and `frozenset`:

```py
lst = [[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 7], [5, 2], [6, 1], [7, 3], [8, 9], [9, 8]]

output = set(map(frozenset, lst))

print(output)
# {frozenset({1, 6}), frozenset({2, 5}), frozenset({3, 7}), frozenset({8, 9})}
```

If you want to have a list of lists, then you can append the following:

```py
output = list(map(list, output))
print(output)
# [[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 7], [8, 9]]
```